# Hyphen usage on Linux command options

Tags: linux, command

Until recently, I was under the impression that by convention, all Linux command options were required to be prefixed by a hyphen (-). So for example, the instruction `ls –l` executes the `ls` command with the `l` option (here we can see that the `l` option is prefixed by a hyphen).

Life was good until I got to the chapter of my Linux for beginners book that explained the `ps` command. There I learned that I could write something like `ps u U xyz` where as far as I can tell, the`u` and `U` are options that are not required to be prefixed by a hyphen. Normally, I would have expected to have to write that same command as something like `ps –uU xyz` to force the usage of a hyphen.

I realize that this is probably a stupid question but I was wondering if there is a particular reason as to why the `ps` command does not follow what I thought was the standard way of specifying command options (prefixing them with hyphens). Why the variation? Is there a particular meaning to specifying hyphen-less options like that?

Comment: ps is just an old program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a handful of old programs on Unix that were written when the conventions were not as widely adopted, and `ps` is one of them. Another example is `tar`, although it has since been updated to allow options both with and without the `-` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best practice concerning hyphenation is to use them as the default go-to. More times than not, they have accepted hyphen prefixes to most or all flags/options available for commands. Happy to be corrected if I am wrong in this instance. I am still new to this myself! :)